# Using Bitmap in ViewFlipper

Tags: android

I am facing problem with using images in `ViewFlipper`.

In my app in `MainActivity` I have created a list using list adapter.
whenever list view item clicked it is going to take another layout having `ViewFlipper` in it.

While testing my app listview opening perfectly. but whenever I clicked list item app broken and showing `OutOfMemory` error. I heard that in this case use BitMap for images. But I dont know how to use it and where to use it.

Please Explain me this problem..

**acivity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mithmart.testlistviewapp.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        CustomListView adapter = new CustomListView(MainActivity.this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PicsActivity.class);
                    String pathpic = "1";
                    intent.putExtra("Path_Picture", pathpic);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PicsActivity.class);
                    String pathpic = "2";
                    intent.putExtra("Path_Picture", pathpic);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PicsActivity.class);
                    String pathpic = "3";
                    intent.putExtra("Path_Picture", pathpic);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                //Here i have write code for 3 list items for checking perpose
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_pics.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.mithmart.testlistviewapp.PicsActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ViewFlipper>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Previous" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Next" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**PicsActivity.java**
    public class PicsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    Button btnPre, btnNxt;
    String newString;
    LinearLayout pics;

    int[] oneclick = {R.drawable.animal001, R.drawable.animal002, R.drawable.animal003, R.drawable.animal004,
            R.drawable.animal005, R.drawable.animal006, R.drawable.animal007, R.drawable.animal008,
            R.drawable.animal009, R.drawable.animal010};

    int[] twoclick = {R.drawable.cartoon1, R.drawable.cartoon2, R.drawable.cartoon3, R.drawable.cartoon4,
            R.drawable.cartoon5, R.drawable.cartoon6, R.drawable.cartoon7, R.drawable.cartoon8,
            R.drawable.cartoon9, R.drawable.cartoon10};

    int[] threeclick = {R.drawable.rakul1, R.drawable.rakul2, R.drawable.rakul3, R.drawable.rakul4,
            R.drawable.rakul5, R.drawable.rakul6, R.drawable.rakul7, R.drawable.rakul8,
            R.drawable.rakul9, R.drawable.rakul10};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pics);

        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        btnPre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPre);
        btnNxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNxt);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            if (extras == null) {
                newString = null;
            } else {
                newString = extras.getString("Path_Picture");

                if (newString.equals("1")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < oneclick.length; i++) {

                        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inSampleSize = 4;
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), oneclick[i], options);

                        setFlipperImage(oneclick[i]);

                    }
                } else if (newString.equals("2")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < twoclick.length; i++) {
                        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inSampleSize = 4;
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), twoclick[i], options);

                        setFlipperImage(twoclick[i]);
                    }
                } else if (newString.equals("3")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < threeclick.length; i++) {

                        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inSampleSize = 4;
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplication().getResources(), threeclick[i], options);

                        setFlipperImage(threeclick[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == btnNxt) {
            viewFlipper.showNext();
        } else if (view == btnPre) {
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
    }

    private void setFlipperImage(int res) {
        Log.i("Set Filpper Called", res + "");
        ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        image.setBackgroundResource(res);
        viewFlipper.addView(image);
    }
}
```

**ListView Adapter**

```
public class CustomListView extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    String[] titles = {"first", "Second", "Third", "Forth, "Fifth","Sixth", "Seventh","Eighth","Ninth","Tenth" };

    int[] mainImages = {R.drawable.rakul001, R.drawable.rakul002, R.drawable.rakul003,
            R.drawable.rakul004, R.drawable.rakul005, R.drawable.rakul006, R.drawable.rakul007,
            R.drawable.rakul008, R.drawable.rakul009, R.drawable.rakul010};


    public CustomListView(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mainImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mainImages[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, null);
        ImageView allimages = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final TextView alltitles = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        String customtitle = alltitles.getText().toString();

        allimages.setImageResource(mainImages[i]);

        alltitles.setText(customtitle + titles[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: your images probably are just too large

Comment: yes they are big file. but   I have searched around google for the problem.  Most of the articals say use bitmap images. idont know how to where to implement that . Please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use scaled bitmap

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), twoclick[i], options);
Bitmap scaledBm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, WIDTH, HEIGHT, true);
```

You can also used Lru bitmap cache from android
see this https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap